# Implementar formulario, fazendo com que a mensagem seja enviada diretamente para meu email

Tags: php, envio-de-email, email

Tenho um formulário de contato no meu site. Ele pega as informações como nome, e-mail, telefone e mensagem. Porém esses dados são exibidos apenas no painel de administração do próprio site. Gostaria que na hora do contato o código pegasse o e-mail informado pelo usuário e enviasse uma mensagem direto para meu e-mail!

Tentei usar a função mail, porém não estou obtendo nenhum sucesso! Como fazer isso então?!

Usei algun:: Tais como

1º.::

```
<?php
    $nome     = $_POST['nome'];     echo $nome; echo "<br>";
    $email    = $_POST['email'];    echo $email; echo "<br>";
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem']; echo $mensagem; echo "<br>";
    $corpo  = "Nome: ".$nome."<BR>\n";
    $corpo .= "Email: ".$email."<BR>\n";
    $corpo .= "Mensagem: ".$mensagem."<BR>\n";
    if(mail("desinatario@site.com","Assunto",$corpo)){
      echo("email enviado com sucesso");
    } else {
      echo("Erro ao enviar e-mail");
    }
?>
```

Nesse exemplo, ele simplesmente retorna "erro ao enviar e-mail", sem mais detalhes.

2.::

```
<?php
    $email_remetente = "eu@seudominio.com";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    $headers .= "From: $email_remetente\n"; // remetente
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $email_remetente\n"; // return-path
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_usuario\n"; // Endereço (devidamente validado) que o seu usuário informou no contato
    $envio = mail("destinatario@algum-email.com", "Assunto", "Mensagem", $headers, "-f$email_remetente");
?>
```

O destinatário sempre será o mesmo - o meu email - o que vai mudar de fato sempre sera o assunto, mensagem e o remetente.

Comment: É possível acrescentar o código com sua tentativa na pergunta? Assim fica mais fácil de ajudarmos com uma solução.

Comment: O servidor de email do localhost foi configurado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizo a classe SMTPMailer para este fim (é necessário pelo menos um GMAIL para isso já que usaremos seu servidor SMTP) estou colocando uns métodos que fazem o uso desta classe (todo documentado).

**Link para download da PHPMailer:** http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

```
    /**
    *String que armazena o email de onde partirá os emails (remetente).
    *@var string
    */
    const GUSER = 'email';

    /**
    *String que armazena a senha do email de onde partirá os emails (remetente).
    *@var string
    */
    const GPWD = 'senha';

    /**
    *String que armazena o email para qual as mensagens serão enviadas (destinatário).
    *@var string
    */
    const GSEND = 'teste';


   static function contactUsEmail(){

        $emailRemetente = $_POST['email'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $mensagem = $_POST["message"];
        $corpoMensagem = '<b>CONCTACT US EMAIL</b>'.'<br /><b>Email Remetente: </b>'.$emailRemetente.
        '<br /><b>Nome:</b>'.$name.'<br /><b>Assunto:</b>'.$subject.'<br /><b>Mensagem:</b>'.$mensagem;

        $sendResult = SendEmail::smtpMailer(SendEmail::GSEND, SendEmail::GUSER, $name, $subject, $corpoMensagem);

        if($sendResult === true){
             echo 'Mensagem Enviada com Sucesso';
        }else{
            echo $sendResult;
        }
    }

    function smtpMailer($destinatario, $remetente, $nomeRemetente, $assunto, $corpo){

        /*
        *Objeto que realizará a composição do email com os dados passados como parametros, 
        *armazenara as configurações do servidor SMTP utilizado e todas as outras configurações 
        *e realizará o envio do email.
        *@var PHPMailer object
        */
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        /**
        *Define o charset do email a ser enviado.
        */
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

        /**
        *Ativa SMTP para uso.
        */
        $mail->IsSMTP();

        /**
        *Não exibirá erros e mensagens, outras configurações possiveis: 
        *Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas.
        */
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

        /**
        *Ativa a autenticação.
        */
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        /**
        *Protocolo utilizado, o gmail (servidor utilizado) requere o uso de tls.
        */
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

        /**
        *SMTP utilizado
        */
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

        /**
        *Porta utilizado para envio de mensagens (ela deverá estar aberta em seu servidor).
        */
        $mail->Port = 587;

        /**
        *Login do usuário utilizado para envio do email (no caso usuário comum do gmail).
        */
        $mail->Username = SendEmail::GUSER;

        /**
        *Senha do login de usuário utilizado para envio do email.
        */
        $mail->Password = SendEmail::GPWD;

        /**
        *Identificação do remetente do email (usuário de email utilizado para envio do 
        *email pelo sistema (logo de propriedade do sistema) e o nome do usuário remetente 
        *(informado na hora da criação do email)) do email.
        */
        $mail->SetFrom($remetente, $nomeRemetente);

        /**
        *Assunto do email.
        */
        $mail->Subject = $assunto;

        /**
        *Corpo do email.
        */
        $mail->Body = $corpo;

        /**
        *Email destinatário do email (de propriedade do sistema).
        */
        $mail->AddAddress($destinatario);

        /**
        *Seta o email como HTML (por padrão ele é text/plain).
        */
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        $sendResult = $mail->Send();

        if(!$sendResult){
            return "<b>Informações do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: só mais um pergunta @Ricardo Henrique! Estou desenvolvendo o script no meu servidor! Porém não da certo! Agora se eu testo o script direto no servidor que vou usar ele definitivamente! Ai da funciona! Você saberia me dizer o porque?

Comment: Eu não sei ao certo o porque deste problema mas eu tenho algumas hipoteses:
1º Porta 587 não esta aberta e livre.
2º Pode haver um firewall no meio do caminho.